# Should I move an interface without any implementations to a library

Tags: java, android, git, kotlin, git-submodules

I work for a company where we maintain 3 projects.
We have decided to move some common code to a separate library recently. Now we use this library in all projects via git submodules conception.

The solution was pretty convenient, so we continued to move common functionality to the library, relieving the main projects. The question I have so far, should I move base interfaces to this library.

For instance, we have a Mapper interface, that is present in every project, but has no common implementations.

It looks like this:

```
interface Mapper<F, T> {

    fun map(from: F): T

}
```

This is not a big deal to write this for every new project, and something says to me that moving it to a library is a bad style, but I can't find any explanation why it is bad exactly. Is there anyone who able to point on the disadvantages of such approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain why this has to be your own interface rather than using one of the several built-in interfaces that do that?

Comment: Maybe the main reason is that I don't know these built-in interfaces. Could you please give an example? 

Anyway, I'm talking not only about Mapper. There are few more base types, that are common for every project.

Comment: In my opinion, if the interface is actually consumed from your library, it makes total sense to put it with the rest of the library, even without implementation. That's actually how you decouple modules.

Comment: That looks like it should just be a normal Kotlin function `(F) -> T`.